# C++ XOR linked list, deleting data

Tags: c++

I have to do XOR linked list. Now im at point that i want to proper way clear memory. I did something like this but it seems doesnt work.

Minimal code i could add to work

```
void deleteAll(Data* head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        cout << "Empty list." << endl;
    else
    {
        if (XOR(head, NULL) == NULL)
        {
            Data* tmp = NULL;
            Data* next;
            while (head)
            {
                next = XOR(head->npx, tmp);
                tmp = head;
                delete head;
                //cout << head->liczba << endl; EDIT <<< this line is not problem
                head = next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the moment when i alocate data

```
Data* tmp = new Data;
    tmp->liczba = num;
    tmp->npx = XOR(*head, NULL);
    if (*head != NULL)
    {
        (*head)->npx = XOR(XOR((*head)->npx,NULL),tmp);
    }
    *head = tmp;
    tmp = NULL;
    delete tmp;
```

In main function after deleting function i run printAll function, then i can see that data has not been cleared.

Edit:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

struct Data {
    int liczba;
    Data* npx;
};

struct Data* XOR(struct Data* prev, struct Data* next)
{
    return (Data*)((uintptr_t)(prev) ^ (uintptr_t)(next));
}

void pushEnd(Data** head, int num)
{
    Data* tmp = new Data;
    tmp->liczba = num;
    tmp->npx = XOR(*head, NULL);
    if (*head != NULL)
    {
        (*head)->npx = XOR(XOR((*head)->npx,NULL),tmp);
    }
    *head = tmp;
    tmp = NULL;
    delete tmp;
}


void printBackward(Data* head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        cout << "Pusta lista." << endl;
    else
    {
        Data* next;
        Data* prev = NULL;
        while (head)
        {
            cout << head->liczba << endl;
            next = XOR(head->npx, prev);
            prev = head;
            head = next;
        }
    }
}

void deleteAll(Data* head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        cout << "Empty list." << endl;
    else
    {
        if (XOR(head, NULL) == NULL)
        {
            Data* tmp = NULL;
            Data* next;
            while (head)
            {
                next = XOR(head->npx, tmp);
                tmp = head;
                delete head;
                head = next;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Data* head = NULL;
    pushEnd(&head, 5);
    pushEnd(&head, 10);
    pushEnd(&head, 7);
    pushEnd(&head, 3);
    printBackward(head);
    cout << head->liczba;
    cout <<endl<< "DEL" << endl;
    deleteAll(head);
    printBackward(head);
}
```

Comment: Not enough code here to properly reproduce your problem. That makes this question less useful to future askers. Consider crafting a [mre] and adding it to the question. As an added bonus, MRE is a powerful debugging technique that will probably expose the mistake and solution and let you fix  the code without any help.

Comment: Defererencing `head` in `tmp->npx = XOR(*head, NULL);`, is that a typo or is that really how your code looks? If so, what does `XOR` look like? A [mre] is probably for the best.

Comment: Discuss `if (XOR(head, NULL) == NULL)` with [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Prove your logic with a simple truth table.

Comment: I edited post and give xor function

Comment: if (XOR(head, NULL) == NULL)   it checks if my head pointer is last element at linked list, so it checks if next element is NULL ( XOR something ^ NULL = NULL ). In my case it is always true (for now)

Comment: I don't understand how `XOR(*head, NULL)` or `if (*head != NULL)` can compile

Comment: @TedLyngmo   XOR(*head, NULL) return NULL (as i said above XOR smth ^ NULL = NULL) and it's not XOR(head, NULL) == NULL but XOR(head->npx,NULL)

Comment: They already asked for a [mcve]. Just make it and you will get plenty of help.

Comment: From what I can see, `head` is a `Data*`. which makes `XOR(*head, NULL)` invalid, since `XOR` takes two `Data*` as arguments, not `Data` or `Data&` - Edit: Ok, `head` was actually a `Data**` - that changes things

Comment: @CostantinoGrana okey, i think i did it in edit now, at bottom.

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry, i missed parameters... I did right there Data** head as parameter. I updated code above

Comment: @Kawson Much better. Just a note: `tmp = NULL; delete tmp;` is a no-op. You can remove both those lines at the end of the `pushEnd` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `deleteAll` you have a line preventing all deletions:

```
if(XOR(head, NULL) == NULL) {   // remove this line
```

Your `deleteAll` functions also takes a `Data*` and all changes you make to `head` will be local to the function only. A minimal change needed that should make it work is to take `head` as a `Data*&` - that is, a reference to a pointer, so that all changes to do to `head` in your function are actually made to the `head` you defined in `main`.

Example:

```
void deleteAll(Data*& head) {
    if(head == nullptr)
        cout << "Empty list." << endl;
    else {
        Data* tmp = nullptr;
        Data* next;
        while(head) {
            next = XOR(head->npx, tmp);
            tmp = head;
            delete head;
            head = next;
        }
    }
}
```

You still call it the same way: `deleteAll(head);`.

If you prefer calling it with `deleteAll(&head);` you could define the function like this:

```
void deleteAll(Data** head) {
    if(*head == nullptr)
        cout << "Empty list." << endl;
    else {
        Data* tmp = nullptr;
        Data* next;
        while(*head) {
            next = XOR((*head)->npx, tmp);
            tmp = *head;
            delete *head;
            *head = next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user4581301 :-) Quack quack rubber ducky!

Comment: Oh. it works. I knew tthat was local and i even tried to work on original head. But i used as parameter Data** head. If we do ** doesnt we use original head in this case?
And why we have to work on original head, i think that head doesnt store data, it store only address to data, doesnt it?

Comment: Yes, that'll have the same effect, but requires a little more typing inside the function and at the call site. You could also change your `pushEnd` to `void deleteAll(Data*& head)` and then you could work on `head` as a `Data*` instead of a `Data**` - which makes it a little simpler i.m.o. It's also simpler to call `pushEnd(head, 5);` instead of `pushEnd(&head, 5);`

Comment: Okey, so it is like i thought but it doesnt work. Is it proper ?

`void deleteAll(Data** head)
{
    if (*head == NULL)
        cout << "Empty list." << endl;
    else
    {
        if (XOR((*head), NULL) == NULL)
        {
            Data* tmp = NULL;
            Data* next;
            while (*head)
            {
                next = XOR((*head)->npx, tmp);
                tmp = *head;
                delete *head;
                *head = next;
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: No, that's why the `*&` is easier. You compare a `Data**` with `NULL` when you wanted to compare a `Data*` with `NULL`.

Comment: But i did `if (*head == NULL)` so it should be fine, doesnt it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I have a hard time reading the rest of the code in the comment but I _think_ it is ok.

Comment: Ok, it works , i had mistake in my code (i dont even know where and with ** it didnt work [probably () somewhere around *head]) and now works fine. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Kawson You're welcome! Btw, I recommend using `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.